# Does a new motorcycle headlight need to have the exact power consumption specs as the old one to avoid overworking the regulator rectifier?

Tags: motorcycle

My OEM motorcycle headlight is listed as 12V 60/55W (STANLEY). When swapping to a different style of headlight assembly and globe with lower power requirements, for example 35W instead of 55W does this mean the regulator rectifier is going to work harder to get rid of the extra power flowing through that the new headlight isn't using?

I see lots of videos of people changing to LED and videos about changing headlights in general but almost no one talks about the mismatch in power consumption between the new and old headlights and how this will affect the electrical system.

Do people who swap headlights hope for the best (or know from experience) that their regulator rectifier etc will work with no issues?, this is option 1. Option 2 is only swap to a headlight which matches the original headlight power requirements. Option 3 is calculate the difference in power consumption and draw that amount of power so that the regulator rectifier isn't overworking.

Please forgive my ignorance on the correct terminology. I'm learning this now and the swap is because I have a used motorcycle with an ugly custom headlight which I would like to swap to a different style (not specifically the original OEM headlight) without damaging the electrical system. My exact question is does it have a negative impact to the motorcycle electrical system (regulator rectifier, stator etc) by not replacing a headlight / headlight assembly with the same specs as the original headlight?

Comment: Is it a modern motorcycle with a modern electrical system? Or an antique? Don't laugh, I had a Craftsman/Husqvarna riding mower which had peculiar requirements for the headlights since the electrical system was so very cost-optimized.  I was hoping to add aux lights and LED the headlights.

Comment: Watts is a result of load, not what determines load. If you install something that uses less watts, the whole system "provides" less watts. If you install something that uses more watts, the whole system "provides" more watts - even if the conductors or supply aren't rated to do it. This is why its dangerous to go over, but almost never dangerous to go under.

Comment: @JamesT That is not correct. Motorcycles don't work like that. The charging/electrical system is designed in such a way to feed through 100% of power requirements whether that power is used by the lights or not. If the power is not used, the regulator is then worked harder to get rid of this power. The manufacturer knows how much power is required and designs the system to produce that much power. Changing to LED/lower powered lights means the regulator is worked harder than what is possible new out of the factory.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It's not antique or a niche bike. I was hoping for an answer to apply to most bikes. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

A lower wattage lamp will draw less power. There is no "unused power flowing through the headlight that has to be got rid of."

There should only be a problem if you install a lamp with a *higher* wattage than rated, drawing more power than the circuits expect. *Then* you might be overworking other components.

Consider what is happening when the lamp is turned off: there is no unused power to get rid of. None is even drawn from the battery.

---

Added after comments about the different circuitry in a motorcycle:

Countries have different "construction and use" regulations, and some require the headlight to be always on (UK does not), which may mean there is no 'off' switch, and manufacturers release slightly different versions to comply with local laws.

It would seem unlikely that they fit a different heatsink for versions that have no 'off' switch, and far more likely that the heat sink will be capable off dissipating all the unused power when the circuits are under no load.

After all, if the headlamp bulb blows, they would not want the circuitry wrecked by an overload of unused power.

Comment: See, and you even get an upvote for it :o)

Comment: To expand on this, in most vehicles including motorcycles, rather than using a linear regulator or DC-DC regulator on the output of the alternator, the power is regulated using alternator field excitation. This modulates the power supplied to the rotor to regulate the total power generated by the stator to match the load. This means that the alternator adjusts the amount of mechanical energy converted to electrical energy, generating less energy and imposing less load on the engine if less power is drawn.

Comment: It's just like your house - there's no "extra power to get rid of" at night when you turn off all the lights, or is there anything extra when you turn on the oven, water heater or dryer. (TBF, there are situations when _everyone_ turns up their AC in the afternoon/evening, but that's a total power consumption issue that the PoCo deals with, nothing in the individual house.)

Comment: @user1937198 Incorrect. What you say is correct for cars. Motorcycles, ATVs and such use a permanent magnet generator, called a stator. That is followed by a rectifier and shunt regulator, if you looked at a motorcycle regulator, you'd note that it has large heatsinks. The generator is producing 100% power all the time, any excess is dumped as heat. This is because motorcycles have small electrical systems, and engine components are weight, volume, and cost sensitive.

Comment: Regardless, the circuitry will be designed to handle any power use from zero up to the maximum rating. Individual circuits will be fused to prevent overload.

Comment: @user71659 Would you say this extra heat is negligible or will it cause damage / wear parts out faster? I gave a tick to the current answer because if got so many upvotes, do you believe this answer is incorrect? Will you submit an answer as well please if this is the case? What if I have defective heat sinks and this was never a problem but now that I'm using a lower power headlight this little extra heat introduces a problem that otherwise wouldn't occur if I just use a factory spec headlight, is this possible?

Comment: @JohnDoe, someone does (there was a downvote). Leaving the lamp off results in more "unused power" than having it on. I really can't understand what your concern is. If the heat sinks are defective there will be a problem regardless of using a lower wattage bulb.

Comment: @Weather Vane it sounds like your original answer isn't the same as how you put it in your comment. You said "there is no unused power", now you say leaving the lamp off results in more unused power, like you agree with user1937198. If the lamp off results in more unused power, then reducing the power drawn by the lamp from 65w down to 35w will also result in more unused power. My original concern is of the electrical/charging system having to dissipate the extra unused power resulting in worn parts, blown fuses, built up heat causing more wear etc.

Comment: There isn't any unused power going through the bulb. If the circuit is as user1937198 says, how can having a lower power bulb be more potentially damaging than having it switched off? What they say is a red herring.

Comment: I said flowing through the regulator/rectifier not the bulb.

My bike only has low beam and high beam like many bikes, no off. A lower power 35W bulb will cause more power to flow to the regulator/rectifier (the power that it's saving isn't saved, it's diverted to the regulator/rectifier). Having it off will cause even more power to the regulator/rectifier. It's not like your answer of drawing power, there is 100% power sent through the system if the bulb takes it or not, if the bulb doesn't take it then the regulator/rectifier does, taking more power than was possible from the factory bulb.

Answer (score -1):

I asked the original question, I've found out some further information after researching.

There are different types of regulators which act differently based on:

- How you ride (racing can generate more electrical power with higher
  RPM).
- The amount of power drawn by your bulb also affects the regulator (if
  you use a lower power bulb, LED or switch off the bulb).

Some regulator examples include MOFSET and series regulators.

If you change to a lower power bulb, it doesn't just draw less power, it causes that unused power to work the regulator harder. So you need to be careful to match your power requirements and regulator type with a lower power bulb.

This youtube video describes it exactly at 10:58. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXbZZZWLtzY